# Can't get pubDate to output in Yahoo! Pipes?

Tags: date, rss, feed, yahoo-pipes, pubdate

In one of my RSS feeds in Yahoo! Pipes, I'm formatting dates using the Date Formatter module and using the format %K so they are pubDate-compliant. In Pipe Output, my four dates appears as follows: `Wed, 25 Jul 2012 03:30:00 +0000`, `Mon, 16 Jul 2012 06:30:00 +0000`, `Wed, 11 Jul 2012 07:00:00 +0000`, and `Wed, 27 Jun 2012 13:00:00 +0000`.

However, in the RSS feed output, none of these dates appear. Are they formatted incorrectly? Why does Yahoo! Pipes not output these dates?

Comment: It would help if we could see the pipe..

Comment: It's a private pipe; I'd rather not make it public. Anyway, it appears as though NO pubDates get through Yahoo! Pipes. I tested some popular feeds (I can't remember which; probably for NY Times, CNN, etc.) which had dates, ran them through Pipes, and they lost their dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I now realize that I need to output dates to `y:published` rather than `pubDate`. This doesn't seem to be widely documented. Even Googling `y:published` doesn't return many results.

Here are the more detailed steps:

1. You have an easy-to-read date such as `8 Jan 2013` in its own field, such as `pubDate` (name doesn't matter; it's just used in `Step 2`).
2. Connect your feed to a `Loop` module. Inside that module, put the `Date Builder` module, and specify the field where the date is found (such as `pubDate`).
3. Still in the `Loop` module, select "assign results to" and enter `item.y:published`.

That should output the date in the RSS output in the `pubDate` field, and it should therefore be readable in any RSS reader.

Comment: I had the same issue but the above solution didn't work for me; it's possible that Yahoo Pipes have changed their API or that my circumstances were different. Either way, the solution that worked for me is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357960/yahoo-pipes-rss-pubdate-showing-as-undefined-when-viewed-through-google-feeds/19443136?noredirect=1#comment28837740_19443136 - credit due to @janos, who solved it.

Comment: I think Yahoo! Pipes did indeed change things a bit since this post. I believe they actually made it easier; you don't even have to follow my steps anymore. Any date you put in `pubDate` is automatically outputted correctly to the RSS feed, from what I've seen.

Comment: I am still not able to output a pubDate in my pipe. The strange thing is, when I edit the source I can see the item.pubDate in the output preview, but when I view the final RSS output it is not there. Here is the pipe:  http://pipes.yahoo.com/colinkaepernick/323be3264eb7311b5ab8724e53495788