# Yahoo pipes Unable to parse into a Date object

Tags: rss, feed, yahoo-pipes

I was trying to create my first pipe today by following some tutorials i found. I wanted to put all the sport sites i read together and sort them by date.

But during the first feed i saw that the items wasn't in order. I checked the RSS feed of the pipe and noticed that pubDate was missing. Then i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692791/cant-get-pubdate-to-output-in-yahoo-pipes) post. I tried to do the same but when i run my pipe i am getting the following error

Unable to parse XXX into a Date object

I checked and the date format was 'Fri,21 Jun 2013 08:46:00 +0200 . No space after the comma. I tried to add it by either regular expressions or string replacement but it didn't work. If i manually time the day it will work.

So basicly this pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=b0e52f1523e9d15b214c2b1201692aec

will give me the warnings but if i copy the date from the warning and put it in the first loop i don't get any error. 
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=a0d5e2cd99fd740b5a1df919ebf8ec40

What am i missing here?

Comment: Yahoo! Pipes is a web app and user-side questions are better for http://WebApps.StackExchange.com/